# What is the Java equivalent to Kotlin's take() method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working on a memory card game that display matches images, the lesson on youtube was in kotlin and there's a method called `take()` that takes int number to display the images according to the number of cardviews i implemented in adapter.
i'm trying to create the game but in java and i need to display the images for all the card i have and can't figure out what is the equivalent for this method `take()` in java

this is the approach i came up with for the list:

```
drawables = new ArrayList<>();
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_face);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_flash);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_flower);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_gift);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_heart);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_house);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_moon);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_plane);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_school);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_send);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_star);
drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_work);
//shuffle both arrays
ArrayList<Integer> secondDrawable = new ArrayList<>(drawables);
Collections.shuffle(secondDrawable);
```

Comment: Well, if you have a list, then something like `subList(0, 3)` would be what you're looking for. Or using streams: `stream().limit(3).collect(...)`.

Comment: Not your question, but your code could be much cleaner. Put `import static mypackage.R.drawable.*` at the top and then you can declare all your items in one call with `drawables = Arrays.asList(ic_face, ic_flash, ic_gift, /*...*/);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
drawables.stream().limit(6).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The stream that comes with Java 8 can be used.